# Am I able to have this method return generic return types?

Tags: c#, generics

Am I able to make this method generic?

```
  public static List<int> GetUnshippedOrders(string server,string port,string database,string username,string password, string orderStatus)
  {
        var orderNumbers = new List<int>();
        using (var conn = ConnectToMySql(server, port, database, username, password))
        {            
           var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT OrderNumber FROM orders WHERE OrderStatus = @orderStatus;", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderStatus", orderStatus);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                orderNumbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader[0])); 
            }
        } 
        return orderNumbers;
   }
```

I want to be able to handle various return types as the order number referenced to will change depending upon the schema of the database being connected to, I would prefer not to have to overload this method for each possible return type (plus I want to learn generics).

The database schema is dictated by various web services, none of which are under my control.
Also of special note, orderStatus can be a variety of types as well ( mostly string and int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logic to determine the return type is internal to the method, a generic return type isn't going to help since you need to be able to specify the return type when calling a generic method. You could change the return type to `List<object>` and then handle casting back to the concrete type after the method returns. It's ugly, but it works.

If the caller knows what type to expect when calling the method, you could simply change `List<int>` to `List<T>` and support generics that way.

Comment: if you are unable to determine the type prior to the call how would you determine it on the next line of code (Ie when the method have returned)?

Comment: @RuneFS - Theoretically you would know a range of types to be returned. You could test the object returned against those types and then cast appropriately.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Thanks - worked the way I needed it to for my testing.

Comment: Yes you could but then again that's not just UGLY but something more nasty than that. I do believe it will bring forth the code version of Belzebub

Comment: @RuneFS - Sometimes it is a necessary evil. Nowhere near as bad as a misguided GOTO.

Comment: oh and of course it would help you a bit :) since all that code could then be wrap up in a generic method which could be used where everywhere seeing that casting it to a specific type would do you little good unless you know which specific type it's cast to. So in the end you will end up somewhere where you know which type to expect and viola you can pass a T to your generic method so it's hardly ever going to be a **necessary** evil. It will always be something you can design your way around if you so wish

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public static List<T> GetUnshippedOrders<T>(string server,string port,string database,string username,string password, string orderStatus) where T : class
{
    var orderNumbers = new List<T>();
    using (var conn = ConnectToMySql(server, port, database, username, password))
    {            
       var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT OrderNumber FROM orders WHERE OrderStatus = @orderStatus;", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderStatus", orderStatus);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            orderNumbers.Add((T)(reader[0])); 
        }
    } 
    return orderNumbers;
}
```

Comment: If you can't always convert the results to `T` with a cast you may want to add an extra parameter that's a `Func<object, T>` to allow a custom conversion method that converts the `object` into the desired result.

Comment: @vittore - I was trying to stay in line with the code and just cast there. Your suggestion would work as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (don't forget usings):

```
public static List<T> GetUnshippedOrders<T>(string server,string port,string database,string username,string password, string orderStatus, Func<IDataReader, T> factoryMethod)
  {
        var results = new List<T>();
        using (var conn = ConnectToMySql(server, port, database, username, password))
        {            
           using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT OrderNumber FROM orders WHERE OrderStatus = @orderStatus;", conn))
            {
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderStatus", orderStatus);
               using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                   results.Add(factoryMethod(reader)); 
                 }
               }
             }
        } 
        return results;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the caller knows the return type**

If the caller knows the type it can expect for the order number, you can change the definition to

```
public static List<T> GetUnshippedOrders<T>(string server,string port,string database,string username,string password, string orderStatus)
```

Usage:

```
List<int> orderNumbers = GetUnshippedOrders<int>(...);
```

**If the method knows the return type**

If the method *GetUnshippedOrders* must determine the type for order numbers, you cannot use generics.

Comment: **downvoter**: From the FAQ: *Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!*